# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sll

I cleared all chache but didn't get solution.

This site can’t provide a secure connectionstackoverflow.com sent an invalid response[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFLXA.jpg).
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score -1):

Follow this Youtube Video : https://youtu.be/QbMyqAJT_-c

This worked for my pc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).